# java gui terminal application sending limited data

Tags: java

i am trying to develop pocketsphinx app. using terminal java gui-code          in raspberry pi. The code is below. when started the application after 28   line its stops. Where is the problem? Thanks..
   kamil

```
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    //MIC TASK
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

public class MIC_TASK implements Runnable {

public void run() {

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = null;
// sending pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes ... command
try {
proc = rt.exec("pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -hmm /usr/local     /share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k "
+ "-lm /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en/4135.lm -dict   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en/4135.dic");

 } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }///

 InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
 String line = null;

 while (true) {



  try {
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    textArea_1.append(line+"\n\r");
    System.out.println(line);

                        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
                    }

    }
```

Comment: "when started the application after 28 line its stops" 28 lines of what? What should the application do? When you say it stops you mean it just hangs there? Any exception? Anything at all?

Comment: the code is sending  command to the pocketsphins after 28 lines of answer, program halts..

Comment: at normally if i use terminal program to communicate with the pocketsphins everythings ok. if i use java terminal application 28 lines of answer(from microphone) it hangs